# ids vs map vs pluck in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { ta_query.all.map{ |ta| ta.id } }
  x.report { ta_query.pluck(:id) }
  x.report { ta_query.ids }
end
```

I've tested this and ids is the fastest one but I can't find any resource saying its better to use ids than pluck, all articles seem to discuss pluck vs select instead :/ Any idea why ids is faster?

Comment: Your benchmark is wrong: `#ids` is same as `pluck(:id)` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L229-L235

Comment: But they are all the wrong answer in 99% of cases. Instead just pass the relation so that it can be used to create a subquery instead of creating two queries.

Comment: `.ids` and `.pluck(:id)` both run the same query. Most probably, your db has already the query results and that's why you got a "faster" response in the `.ids` benchmark; however, in production systems, it will be the same.

Comment: I second @max best bet is to use `select(:id)`, while passing the entire relation to a conditional WHERE will cause this transformation I prefer to avoid "rails magic" where possible to provide in code clarity. If you really *need* an iterative list of ids it would recommend `select(:id).each` to avoid loading all the ids at once

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk well technically it has the overhead of a method call but you're right in that the difference is negible. A better benchmark would be `A.where(b_id: b.ids)` vs `A.where(b_id: b)` on a large data set, and look at the memory consumption of both.

Comment: And use `A.connection.clear_query_cache` between bechmarks to remove the caching issue noted by @RocKhalil.